# Separating words in index into sections starting with the first letter in bold

Tags: sectioning, xetex, imakeidx

I am typesetting a Malayalam book using xelatex. It has two indices, namely, "name" and "subject", for which I am using imakeidx. Now, I would like to separate the list of words with a heading in bold of the first letter, as seen in many books. That is, the list of words beginning with c in the index will start with a capital "C" in bold like a subheading. One solution for this in books with a single index is to use a style file with makeindex, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group?fbclid=IwAR0p59kMRzYt9vI0omgIsKAjDFFvZDQ5VqM05wqSsynri4G2mSO30ZzsgEk)
That is possible when you call makeindex separately after compiling the book. But in my case, when using imakeidx, I don't have to call makeindex separately, but indices also are generated along with the xelatex compilation. I even tried the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245368/how-to-create-a-ist-file-for-the-purpose-of-customizing-the-index) for imakeidx, but that too didn't work! So, I am not sure how I can get that style in my index. I tried using the stylefile as an option in the call to \makeindex command that has to be included in the preamble, but it doesn't work. I am giving below an MWE of the problem.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\malayalamfont[Script=Malayalam,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Rachana.ttf}
\setmainfont{Rachana}
\setromanfont{FreeSerif}
\let\malayalamfontsf\sffamily
\let\malayalamfontrm\rmfamily
\def\xsans#1{{\malayalamfontsf#1}}
\def\xromn#1{{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont#1}}
\newfontfamily\engfont{FreeSerif}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\myfont}{\engfont}
\setdefaultlanguage{malayalam}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=subject,title=വിഷയശബ്ദാവലി,columns=2,intoc=true]
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s pyro,columns=2,intoc=true]
\begin{document}

\index[subject]{എയറോണമി} 

അഹമദാബാദ് ടെക്‌സ്റ്റൈൽ ഇൻഡസ്ട്രീസ് റിസർച്ച് അസോസിയേഷൻ\index[subject]{അഹമദാബാദ് ടെക്‌സ്റ്റൈൽ ഇൻഡസ്ട്രീസ് റിസർച്ച് അസോസിയേഷൻ}

Ahmedabad Textile Industry's Research Association, ATIRA\index[subject]{Ahmedabad Textile   Industry's Research Association, ATIRA} 

\clearpage

അറ്റോമിക് പവർ പ്ലാന്റ്, താരാപൂർ\index[subject]{അറ്റോമിക് പവർ പ്ലാന്റ്, താരാപൂർ}

ഗ്യാസ് ടർബൈൻ റിസർച്ച് എസ്റ്റാബ്ലിഷ്‌മെന്റ്\index[subject]{ഗ്യാസ് ടർബൈൻ റിസർച്ച് എസ്റ്റാബ്ലിഷ്‌മെന്റ്}

എയറോനോട്ടിക്കൽ ഡെവലപ്‌മെന്റ് ഏജൻസി\index[subject]{എയറോനോട്ടിക്കൽ ഡെവലപ്‌മെന്റ് ഏജൻസി}

റ്റാറ്റാ ഇൻസ്റ്റിറ്റ്യൂട്ട് ഒഫ് ഫണ്ടമെന്റൽ റിസർച്ച്\index[subject]{റ്റാറ്റാ ഇൻസ്റ്റിറ്റ്യൂട്ട് ഒഫ് ഫണ്ടമെന്റൽ റിസർച്ച്} 

ആൻട്രിക്‌സ് കോർപറേഷൻ\index[subject]{ആൻട്രിക്‌സ് കോർപറേഷൻ} 

ANTRIX Corporation\index[subject]{ANTRIX Corporation}

\printindex[subject]
\end{document}
```

I thank anyone  who can find a solution to this problem in advance.

Comment: your problem is not imakeidx, you can pass options to makeindex with it as you already found out (with options=-s pyro). Your problem is that makeindex doesn't unterstand malayam and utf8 at all. It sorts your index not by the chars but by bytes, and if you use `headings_flag`, it will split up the first *byte*, and you will get lots of errors.  You would need a index program which understand unicode like xindex or xindy to get sensible headings.

Comment: I can understand that. But two points: 1) I have been creating indices without problem using makeindex until now when I needed to create two indices for a book; 2) imakeidx is not giving even an error-ridden index with headings! Astonishingly, I don't get anything different after adding the style file.

Comment: In your example you didn't add the style to the subject index, when I corrected this, I got the headings and the errors.